# Programatically create a menu?

Tags: routes

I can login to /admin/structure/menu and create a new menu. How can my module create a custom menu like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called [menu_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.module/function/menu_save/7) that looks like it will help you out (I assume drupal 7)